# Archiva upload does not reflect in repository

Tags: archiva

I'm using apache archiva and when I upload an artifact into any repository it does not reflect in the repository. It doesn't get saved anywhere. Basically nothing happens. What could the problem be?

Logs:

> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 | java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: java.nio.file.Files.copy(Ljava/nio/file/Path;Ljava/nio/file/Path;[Ljava/nio/file/CopyOption;)Ljava/nio/file/Path;
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:116)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:324)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:240)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:239)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:213)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:131)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:266)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:191)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:242)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1496)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1476)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/11/26 19:20:10 |       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:732)

Comment: first check the logs (archiva.log) file. How are searching your files? (web ui or direct repository browsing)

Comment: @Dee, were you able to resolve the "Upload Artifact" issue? We are running Archiva 2.2.0 and we are having the same problem. We enter details for a new upload on the Web UI and there are no errors reported but, the artifact do not appear in the data repository. The archiva logs under `/opt/apache-archiva/logs` show no indication of anything having happened either...

Comment: Hi @PonderMuse, I don't think we ever did find a solution unfortunately... I hope you manage to crack it though - good luck!

Comment: Hello @Dee, we did crack it in the end. In the Web UI, to upload an artifact we were filling in the form details and then clicking 'Start Upload'. But it turns out that is not enough... to upload the artifact you also have to click 'Save Files' (which we weren't doing). Once we clicked 'Save Files' then the artifact did upload into the repository okay. Unfortunately the web UI is not very intuitive enough and doesn't make that 'Save Files' button needing to be clicked obvious enough.

Comment: Oh you're right! I remember doing this as well! Thank you for your feedback ! :)

Answer (score 1):

The file upload using archiva is totally non-intuitive, it took me about two hours to finally work it out:

1. Fill in the form
2. Click the **Choose File** button and find your .jar
3. Click **Start Upload** button
4. IMPORTANT!!!!  Then click the **Save Files** button (don't ask why this extra button is needed)